# IdP initiated SSO with Okta IdP and Azure B2C SP via SAML

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, okta

We have a partner we are integrating with.  We want to add a link to their system so they can click on it, automatically get logged into our Azure B2C and redirected to a specific page on our site. We have the requirement that they use SAML to connect.

These are the steps I have followed. I am not sure if I am missing something or if I need to try another path like building .net a bridge SP to connect to the Okta IdP and then redirect the user.

1. setup and Okta IdP
2. written a C# web app
3. Connected the web app directly to the Okta IdP, just to test
4. Posted the web app to azure
5. Created custom policies for the Okta service provider in Azure B2C
6. Create user journey Azure B2C
7. In Azure application insights I keep getting "Exception" with no detail.
8. If I look at the SAML request in the browser I end up getting this 404
   https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml/client/perftrace?tx=b7024f56-034f-4edb-9d60-386514c037f3&p=null

   [Claims provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6dRz.png)

[user journey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik2Jh.png)

metadata url

```html
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.okta.com/exkat2zx10HirumDC696">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIID...</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://XXX.okta.com/app/XXX_testsamlbridge_1/exkat2zx10HirumDC696/sso/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://XXX.okta.com/app/XXX_testsamlbridge_1/exkat2zx10HirumDC696/sso/saml"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

B2C_1A_OktaSecret

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "updatedUtc":"12/10/2021 4:57:15 AM",
      "tenantID":"XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
      "storageKeyId":"B2C_1A_OktaSecret"
   },
   "keys":[
      {
         "kid":"30D7ACFD91E97D5733BB4388C0C45350120A2092",
         "exp":1952890376,
         "nbf":1637357516,
         "x5c":[
            "MIIDqDCCApCgAwIBAgIGAX06HeGMMA0GCSqGSIb..."
         ],
         "x5t":"MNes_ZHpfVczu0OIwMRTUBIKIJI",
         "kty":"RSA",
         "e":"AQAB",
         "n":"q1XSJo0UyHeCIIO2NfnIU5VC5leYRZvtITk..."
      }
   ]
}
```

I went through all three methods and found my error in one.

Method 1 Exceptions, found but didn't tell me anything new
Method 2 trace, didn't find any traces which was weird
Method 3 trace export. well there were no traces so I still couldn't find it.

I added screen shots below.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK7wE.png)

[Exception log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woxLU.png)

[Trace log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arwwh.png)

[Search Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbbNw.png)

Comment: How are you testing/running the SAML B2C custom policy? That 404 (8) is not the cause of the problem. Is `B2C_1A_OktaSecret` a certificate? It should be a certificate. Is the metadata URL accessible in the browser publicly?

Comment: Yes the B2C_1A_OktaSecret is actually a cert and the metadata url I can view in my browser.

here is B2C_1A_OktaSecret 
{
 "metadata": {
  "updatedUtc": "12/10/2021 4:57:15 AM",
  "tenantID": "XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
  "storageKeyId": "B2C_1A_OktaSecret"
 },
 "keys": [
  {
   "kid": "30D7ACFD91E97D5733BB4388C0C45350120A2092",
   "exp": 1952890376,
   "nbf": 1637357516,
   "x5c": [
    "MIIDqDCCApCgAwIBAgIGAX06HeGMMA0GCSqGSIb..."
   ],
   "x5t": "MNes_ZHpfVczu0OIwMRTUBIKIJI",
   "kty": "RSA",
   "e": "AQAB",
   "n": "q1XSJo0UyHeCIIO2NfnIU5VC5leYRZvtITk..."
  }
 ]
}

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/debugging-custom-policy-exceptions-in-azure-ad-b2c-6703f53c4e15 Use message type 3 technique i.e. traces / export / open with Notepad++. That should show you the error.

Comment: I tried looking for a more useful error but I didn't find anything useful

Comment: I was surprised that traces didn't have anything in it.